# Extract specific numbers with decimals from a string?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to extract the numbers from a string as follows:

string = "Vol. 20.0 4.44 406.5 419.3 419.3"

I want to be able to specific which number I want, i.e GetNumber(string, 2) = 4.44 or GetNumber(string, 4) = 419.3

Fine with either a vba function or excel formula solution.

Comment: With `VBA` you can use `temp = string.Split(" ")`. This splits the string by a space. You can get the first number with `temp(2)` the second number with `temp(3)`and so on.

Comment: This can also be done with formulas.

Comment: @MG92 excel vba doesnt seem to recognize .split function?

Comment: It would be `temp = Split(string," ")` and it will start with index `0` so make the appropriate changes.

Answer (score 0):

This code removes the first array variable, and allows the user to select what element to use.

```
Dim arrSep As Variant: arrSep = Split("Vol. 20.0 4.44 406.5 419.3 419.3", Space(1))

Const arrDelim As String = "||"

Dim temparr As String: temparr = Join(arrSep, arrDelim) 'build the temporary array

'Rebuilt the array, removing the first element group
arrSep = Split(Mid$(temparr, InStr(1, temparr, arrDelim) + Len(arrDelim), Len(temparr)), arrDelim)

'Allow user to select array element
Dim UserInput As Long: UserInput = InputBox("Input value from 0 to 4 to select specific array value")

'Set variable for user selected value
Dim Val As Variant: Val = CDbl(arrSep(UserInput))

'MsgBox Val
'Or
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A37").Value = Val 'change sheet and range to your requirements
```